# Why is Chrome is causing these span icons to be in different colours?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I think this is linked to a new version of Chrome that's been installed as that's the only thing different I can think of that has occured, but can't prove it.

I have a series of CSS span classes to show different astrology icons, which should all be the same colour as this:

```
.ai {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    color:#74347a;
}
.ai.aries:before {
    content:"\2648";
}
.ai.taurus:before {
    content:"\2649";
}
.ai.gemini:before {
    content:"\264A";
}
.ai.cancer:before {
    content:"\264B";
}
.ai.leo:before {
    content:"\264C";
}
.ai.virgo:before {
    content:"\264D";
}
.ai.libra:before {
    content:"\264E";
}
.ai.scorpio:before {
    content:"\264F";
}
.ai.sagittarius:before {
    content:"\2650";
}
.ai.capricorn:before {
    content:"\2651";
}
.ai.aquarius:before {
    content:"\2652";
}
.ai.pisces:before {
    content:"\2653";
}
```

On every browser other than Chrome, I get the desired effect:
[image]

But then in Chrome, there seems to be a very strange colour cycle going on, with no explanation in Inspector.

[image]

[image]

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/eh1Lku5m/), hoping it would show these colours, but just checking it in FireFox and Chrome, actually shows the proper behaviour, which isn't helpful to anyone, so it must be on my site. But there's nothing obvious.

I thought it would be the Bootstrap CSS, which I disabled, but it's still there.

[image]

Comment: Have you used the inspector to see the elements that are being affected? Are there any unexpected classes or rules being applied to them? Maybe the elements are inheriting rules from other elements or similar?

Comment: No extra classes, and in the inspector is showing the set colour from CSS, which isn't being overridden by anything else. There's literally no mention of any of these other colours anywhere.

Comment: There's clearly something you've not coded into your question effecting the CSS, another style sheet or another class or something... the code you've pasted wont cause the issue you've described. Could you link me to your original? I will nosey at it on Inspector + Firebug.

Comment: Could you try creating a rule that targets the `:before` and `:after` elements to explicitly set the `color` and see if that affects it? e.g. `.ai:before, .ai:after { color: #74347a; }` *you could even try with `!important`*. Unfortunately, everybody's going to be stabbing in the dark, as it's pretty impossible to recreate your error with the code you've supplied.

Comment: @Martin I would love to, but this site is local I'm afraid, and is not net accessible. I have a feeling this may be down to Google Chrome and displaying icons, using spans. The new update is the only thing that's different to yesterday.

Comment: @Geoff I will update my question with a full screenshot of that extra CSS rule, which is applied.. but not rendered still

Comment: some chrome plugin could overriding the color ?

Comment: Got any werido horoscope related browser extensions installed?

Comment: All extensions disabled, and colouring still occuring.

Comment: @GeoffJames doh, my mistake. :-/

Comment: btw icon on my chrome looks lot different from firefox or ur chrome though hehe http://i.imgur.com/ozYnVad.png

Comment: Could this be an EMOJI issue? It's definitely a font issue. The icon looks different in IE too

Comment: It's definitely using native fonts, but even stipulating the font as a generic `Arial,sans-serif` outputs the same thing. This leads me to believe it's purely down to Browser rendering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latest Google Chrome release (v53) support for Color Emoji fonts has been activated, the font Segoe UI Emoji (which is used to render these special characters according to your screenshot) is such a font where each character has predefined colors (even multiple). So, while other browsers still render the icons (emojis actually) in some shade of grey or even black, Chrome now shows the intended color.

See [Google Chrome Changelog](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/52.0.2743.116..53.0.2785.92?pretty=fuller&n=10000) and the [color extension in OpenType fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType#Color) for further information. In Windows 8.1, Microsoft [added unofficial color support to fonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688099.aspx#W8.1), first implemented in the Segoe UI Emoji font:

> A significant font addition is the Segoe UI Emoji font, and color font support. Color fonts use an extension to the OpenType font specification. Color font rendering using the Segoe UI Emoji font allows emoji symbol characters to be displayed using full-color glyphs that are also scalable because they use TrueType glyph outlines. Color emoji display is supported in the DWrite text stack and enabled by default in the HTML and XAML application UI frameworks used for Windows Store apps and in the Windows shell.

To test it on your machine, you could (I do not advise to though) uninstall the Segoe UI Emoji font, all icons should then fallback to the default UTF8 characters and have the color you set in CSS.

See [this discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/352) and the [current proposal](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Feb/0211.html) about possible ways to control the colour rendering of characters in a multi-colour font. This will be available earliest in **CSS Fonts 4**.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did try to read through the list of changes for the new version, but I think I Was just reading the latest latest subversion changes, which had no mention of this at all. I suppose the new question is now, can we stop this override from happening? Is there any way to control the colouring that's happening here?

Comment: This is pretty new stuff and I am not working on Windows machines. There's a way through Windows registry to avoid using the Segoe UI Emoji font, but that's neither recommended nor is it affecting Windows visitors of your future website. Since color property doesn't seem to make a change, did you try to explicitly set the font to the `.ai` class?

Comment: Yeah, I added just the standard `font-family:Arial,san-serif` to the `ai` class, just below the colour, made no difference. Seems a pretty intrusive thing! What's more, is that removing the Wordpress Emoji styles in the header by default, doesn't have any affect on this either.

Comment: Just found some proposals for CSS to be able to control the rendering of multi-coloured fonts, I will add it to the answer. So, short answer, it's probably not yet possible to override the font's colours.

Comment: Beautiful answer, @Paul! Learn something new every day :)

Comment: Not that the emojis are not nice, but I don't know who's idea was to force colors on a private(?) Unicode range... Really, who approved that? Websites used for ages some of those available "icons"/characters, logically, color-defined by the CSS `color` property. Now what? We rely on proposals?

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested in a workaround... 
It could be using a background color and css background-clip property. In my case this is not sufficient as I was using symbols for zodiac signs and they are rendered as colored box. So I have to switch from using symbol entities to use the Windings font. I am not sure about support of Windings in OS other than Windows, so maybe it's not the ultimate solution.

EDIT: Anyway this could be a solution for all those symbols not trapped in a filled box or circle and not relying on color differences to distinguish the content, like the strike in the following snippet:

```css
.BigText {font-size: 30px}

.Windings {font-family: Wingdings;}

.SolidColorIcon {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}

.GradientIcon {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, dodgerblue), color-stop(0.4, skyblue), color-stop(0.6, pink));
 background-image: gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, dodgerblue), color-stop(0.4, skyblue), color-stop(0.6, pink));
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<span class="BigText">
  &#9889 &#9800 ^_`abcdefghi &#9934 
</span><br>

<span class="BigText Windings">
  &#9889 &#9800 ^_`abcdefghi &#9934 
</span><br>

<span class="BigText Windings SolidColorIcon">
  &#9889 &#9800 ^_`abcdefghi &#9934 
</span><br>

<span class="BigText Windings GradientIcon">
  &#9889 &#9800 ^_`abcdefghi &#9934 
</span><br>
```

It seems that with fontsize bigger than 162px Chrome disable the font coded colors giving back control to you to style your font icon

```css
.big-character{
 color: dodgerblue;
 font-size: 163px; 
}
```

```html
Ophiucus symbol is <span class="big-character">&#9934  ⛎</span>
```